# Weird output for decipher function

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher

I have this function that decrypts a caesar encrypted message with a certain key and it gives me the right letters for the output but theres some weird blackspace after it.

Here's the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "proj1.h"
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  char dec[MAXMSGLEN];


  int i = 0;

  while(i < NUMMSGS){
    char solve = SolveCipher(cipher[i], dec);


      if(solve == '\0')
        {
          cout  << "Message #" << (i + 1) << " was not intertesting. " <<endl;
        }
      else
        {
          cout << "Message #" << (i + 1) << ",Key " << solve << endl;
          cout << "\t" << dec << endl;
        }


      i++;

  }


  return 0;
}

void Decipher(char cip[], char key){

  for(int i = 0; i < MAXMSGLEN && cip[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if (cip[i] != ' '){
      cip[i] = char(cip[i] - ((key - 'A')% 26));
      if (cip[i] < 65){
        cip[i] = ((65 - cip[i])-90);

      }

    }
    else{
      cip[i] = cip[i];
    }

  }
}


char SolveCipher(const char cip[], char dec[]){

  char msg[MAXMSGLEN];
  char check[MAXMSGLEN];
  char word[MAXCRIBLEN];

  //Deciphers message with every key
  for(char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++){

    //clears msg
    memset(msg, 0, (sizeof(msg)/sizeof(msg[0])));


    //stores cip in msg
    for(int j = 0; cip[j] != '\0'; j++){
      msg[j] = cip[j];
    }

    Decipher(msg, i);
    cout<< msg <<endl;
  }
  return '\0';
}
```

Here's the encrypted keys I have to loop through:

```
const char cipher[NUMMSGS][MAXMSGLEN] = {
  "HAAHJR HA KHDU AVTVYYVD",
  "DHFGS NBKNBJ ZMC ZKK HR VDKK",
  "Q PIDM JQMJMZ NMDMZ",
  "JCTFGT DGVVGT HCUVGT UVTQPIGT",
  "LRPYE I HTWW XPPE JZF LE ESP NZXXZYD",
  "KLSQ GML LGG DSLW YGL FGLZAF AF EQ TJSAF",
  "QEBC GUR ZVPEBSVYZ ORUVAQ GUR FGNGHR",
  "GZSGZWD NX XTRJBMJWJ JQXJ FY UWJXJSY",
  "RZVOCZM AJM OJHJMMJR HJMIDIB RVMH RDOC GJR XGJPYN",
  "ROBO MYWO LKN XOGC DKVUSXQ DRSC KXN DRKD"
};
```

And FYI I need to keep the parameters as they are now. I cannot change them to strings or anything like that.

If I brute force loop through the black spaces come inside the words

```
ROBO MYWO LKN XOGC DKVUSXQ DRSC KXN DRKD
QNAN LXVN KJM WNFB CJUTRWP CQRB JWM CQJC
PM▒M KWUM JIL VMEA BITSQVO BPQA IVL BPIB
OL▒L JVTL IHK ULD▒ AHSRPUN AOP▒ HUK AOHA
NK▒K IUSK HGJ TKC▒ ▒GRQOTM ▒NO▒ GTJ ▒NG▒
MJ▒J HTRJ GFI SJB▒ ▒FQPNSL ▒MN▒ FSI ▒MF▒
LI▒I GSQI FEH RIA▒ ▒EPOMRK ▒LM▒ ERH ▒LE▒
KH▒H FRPH EDG QH▒▒ ▒DONLQJ ▒KL▒ DQG ▒KD▒
JG▒G EQOG DCF PG▒▒ ▒CNMKPI ▒JK▒ CPF ▒JC▒
IF▒F DPNF CBE OF▒▒ ▒BMLJOH ▒IJ▒ BOE ▒IB▒
HE▒E COME BAD NE▒▒ ▒ALKING ▒HI▒ AND ▒HA▒
GD▒D BNLD A▒C MD▒▒ ▒▒KJHMF ▒GH▒ ▒MC ▒G▒▒
FC▒C AMKC ▒▒B LC▒▒ ▒▒JIGLE ▒FG▒ ▒LB ▒F▒▒
EB▒B ▒LJB ▒▒A KB▒▒ ▒▒IHFKD ▒EF▒ ▒KA ▒E▒▒
DA▒A ▒KIA ▒▒▒ JA▒▒ ▒▒HGEJC ▒DE▒ ▒J▒ ▒D▒▒
C▒▒▒ ▒JH▒ ▒▒▒ I▒▒▒ ▒▒GFDIB ▒CD▒ ▒I▒ ▒C▒▒
B▒▒▒ ▒IG▒ ▒▒▒ H▒▒▒ ▒▒FECHA ▒BC▒ ▒H▒ ▒B▒▒
A▒▒▒ ▒HF▒ ▒▒▒ G▒▒▒ ▒▒EDBG▒ ▒AB▒ ▒G▒ ▒A▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒GE▒ ▒▒▒ F▒▒▒ ▒▒DCAF▒ ▒▒A▒ ▒F▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒FD▒ ▒▒▒ E▒▒▒ ▒▒CB▒E▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒E▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒EC▒ ▒▒▒ D▒▒▒ ▒▒BA▒D▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒D▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒DB▒ ▒▒▒ C▒▒▒ ▒▒A▒▒C▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒C▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒CA▒ ▒▒▒ B▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒B▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒B▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒B▒▒ ▒▒▒ A▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒A▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒A▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒A▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒
```

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You're deciphering characters that aren't part of the message!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So replace MAXMSGLEN with sizeof(cip)??

Comment: No, since that's not the size of the message either. I'd suggest passing in the length of the message as a parameter. Or maybe it has a terminating character? Why not use `std::string` or something like that?

Comment: (In case it's not obvious why `sizeof(cip)` is wrong, thing about this: Since `cip` can hold either a short string or a long string, it's size cannot be the size of the string.)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to copy-paste a complete (buildable) code sample?

Comment: @YePhIcK like put the entire program on the post? The encrypted messages come from a header file fyi

Comment: Well... not the "complete" program, but just enough to illustrate the problem

Comment: @YePhIcK Just updated the post

Comment: @YePhIcK its supposed to skip over the space and continue the decipher on the letters. Does it not?

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile (the way you posted it). It is really non-trivial to debug a lrage-ish codebase in your mind. I'd rather use a debugger - which is why I asked for a complete example

Comment: @YePhIcK ill check all the indentations to make sure they are where they are supposed to be

Comment: what is `cip[i] = ((65 - cip[i])-90);` doing? Seems to be producing **negative** numbers ;-)

Comment: @YePhIcK That's for if the character goes below 'A' so it moves it back to 'Z'

Comment: The correct way to do that would be `cip[i] = (90 - (65 - cip[i]));`. See the updated answer for the full code

Comment: @YePhIcK it works!! Thanks for catching that! Really appreciate it

Comment: @Amike925 debugger is your friend. Next time you have a trouble - try stepping through your code to see where it breaks. Also using temporary variables helps while you are debugging (and don't worry about performance - modern compilers are pretty good at optimizing the temporaries out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are changing the values in a string "all the way" to the `MAXMSGLEN`. Now what happens is you decrypt the main body of the message (say 10 characters) and don't stop but keep on going, updating the values outside of range.

The fix is to stop once you see the "end-of-string" null-terminator `'\0`:

```
void Decipher(char cip[], char key){

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXMSGLEN && cip[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if (cip[i] != ' '){
      cip[i] = char(cip[i] - ((key - 'A')% 26));
      if (cip[i] < 65){
          cip[i] = ((65 - cip[i])-90);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you prefer a more readable code (don't cram too much into the loops' control block):

```
void Decipher(char cip[], char key){

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXMSGLEN; i++){
    if(cip[i] == '\0'){
        break; // end the loop once we reached the string terminator
    }
    if (cip[i] != ' '){
      cip[i] = char(cip[i] - ((key - 'A')% 26));
      if (cip[i] < 65){
          cip[i] = ((65 - cip[i])-90);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**: Avoid using "magic numbers" like `65` and `90`. your code would be way easier to understand if you use `'A'` and `'Z'` instead. Here's the fixed decypher function:

```
void Decipher(char cip[], char key){

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXMSGLEN; i++){
    if(cip[i] == '\0'){
        break; // end the loop once we reached the string terminator
    }
    if (cip[i] != ' '){
      cip[i] = char(cip[i] - ((key - 'A')% 26));
      if (cip[i] < 'A'){
          cip[i] = ('Z' - ('A' - cip[i])); // <-- this is where you were getting negative values
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I loop through all the keys (brute force) those weird black things show up in the middle of the phrase though. Ill add it to the question so you can see

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the string as a `string`:

```
void Decipher(std::string& cip, char key) {
  for (char& ch : cip) {
    if (ch != ' ') {
      ch = char(ch - ((key - 'A') % 26));
      if (ch < 65) {
        ch = ((65 - ch)-90);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way information about its length is also passed and you can simply do a range-based loop through the characters.